# conversion date time utc or gmt to specific time zone EXC_BREAKPOINT error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timezone

Good morning all,
I am looking to create a function in swift and I ask for your help.
The purpose of the code is to convert a time date expressed in UTC or GMT
around a date time expressed for a time zone (timezone)
Syntax:
DateTimeUTCToTimezone (, )

Example:

> DateTimeUTCToTimezone ("201312311200", "Africa/Abidjan")

- This should return "201312311200" because "Africa/Abidjan" is in GMT 0

> DateTimeUTCToTimezone ("201312311200", "Europe/Paris")

- This should return "201312311300" because "Europe/Paris" is in GMT 1

> DateTimeUTCToTimezone ("201309011200", "Europe/Paris")

- This should return "201309011400"

and so on

I managed to create my function generates an execution error on the line

```
return dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)
```

here is the error message

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1003aa100)
```

I'm new to swift and I don't know what to do.

here is the full code:

```
func DateHeureUTCVersTimezone(dateString:String ,TimezoneId:String) -> String
{
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier : TimezoneId)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
return dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)
}
```

Comment: According to the sample strings you provided, I think you should remove the `ss` from your formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the sample strings your provided, you should remove the `ss` part, because your string does not contain any seconds.

```
func DateHeureUTCVersTimezone(dateString:String ,TimezoneId:String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmm"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier : TimezoneId)
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

The exception is because `dt` is `nil` and you're trying to **forcefully unwrap** a `nil` value.

**Solution:**

1. Use **`if-let`** to safely unwrap the `optional` value `dt`.
2. Also, use **`yyyyMMddHHmm`** as the `dateFormat`.

Modify your method to,

```
func dateTimeUTCToTimezone(dateString: String ,timezoneId:String) -> String? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmm"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    if let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) {
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier : timezoneId)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmm"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: dt)
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Output:**

```
dateTimeUTCToTimezone(dateString: "201312311200", timezoneId: "Africa/Abidjan") //201301311200
dateTimeUTCToTimezone(dateString: "201312311200", timezoneId: "Europe/Paris") //201301311300
dateTimeUTCToTimezone(dateString: "201309011200", timezoneId: "Europe/Paris") //201309011400
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answers
The issue is resolved

Comment: Great. Do accept (tick on left) if the answer helped. Happy coding 